# How to handle user editable templates in a cloud stateless hosting environment?

Tags: php, git, symfony, heroku

I've been using since a few year now a home-made PHP CMS/ERP based on Symfony components for my clients. Every site using this framework is hosted on a "classic" linux hosting and I use git to deploy updates. Every site has a folder that stores html/css templates, images and downloadable files that the site admin can access to customize their site. This folder is git-ignored so my framework updates via git won't overwrite the site admin's changes.

I'm thinking about moving those sites in a cloud-based scalable environment like Heroku. As I understand it, this git-ignored folder would be reset every time I'd do git push to Heroku or for every new dyno created. How could I handle this without including this custom folder in the git repo ?

I've thought about storing HTML/CSS templates in the database, and copy them to the drive each time they are updated, after every git deployment or new instance creation. But that wouldn't solve the problem for images or downloadable files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing user-uploaded files locally, Heroku [recommends putting them on an external service like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

You may want to use an existing library for this, e.g. [`KnpGaufretteBundle`](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle):

> Easily use Gaufrette in your Symfony projects.

[Gaufrette itself is](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette) "a PHP5 library that provides a filesystem abstraction layer". [Amazon S3 is one of its supported backends](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette#using-amazon-s3).